# I need to extract each dictionary from list in python?

Tags: python

So I have an API which returns a list as a string

```
words = "[[{'aaa':'123', 'bbb':'456',.....}, {'ccc':'123', 'ddd':'456',.....}, {'eee':'123', 'fff':'456',.....}]]"
```

I need to covert to readable data and remove the nested list

```
word = [{'aaa':'123', 'bbb':'456',.....}, {'ccc':'123', 'ddd':'456',.....}, {'eee':'123', 'fff':'456',.....}]
```

How do I do it in python?

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/952914/758174) answer your problem?

Comment: Are you really asking how to access the first element of a list? Have you made any effort to look for an answer anywhere? What did you find and why didn't that work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a flat list out of list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
import ast
words = ast.literal_eval(words)[0]
```

Comment: I found that the issue was that it thought that `word` was a string not a list so @umgefahren answer did not work. Your solution fixed everything, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As the nested list is just the first item of the superior list you can just pull the first item of that superior list.

```
word = words[0]
```

Comment: It returns only a `[` as result.

Answer (score 0):

you can use list comprehension for that:

```
words = [[a], [b], [c], [d]]
flattened = [val for sublist in words for val in sublist]
```